# pdf not sending as attachment

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer

I have created a php send email script to sending pdf via php mailer along with the attachments I am unable to send as attachments when I am sending an email the attached file is broken it's ok please have a look at my code and let me know what mistake I am doing why the attachments are not sending properly

Here is my html

```
<form method="POST" action="details.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col col_center">
        <input name="first_name" class="firstname text_input" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col col_center">
        <input name="last_name" class="lastname text_input" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col col_center">
        <input name="email" class="email_address text_input" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="col col_center">
        <input name="phone" class="phone text_input" type="tel" placeholder="Phone (with country code)">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $dt['job_title']; ?>" />
    <div class="btn_row">
        <input type="file" value="Attach CV" class="button blue" name="resume" style="width:auto;">
    </div>
    <div class="btn_row">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit_resume" class="button" style="width:auto;">
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my php file

```
$path     = "./uploads/";
    $head     = $_FILES["resume"]["name"];
    $headtype = $_FILES["resume"]["type"];
    $headtemp = $_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"];

    move_uploaded_file($headtemp, $path.$head);

 $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $client_email = $dt[3];
    $mail->setFrom('noreply@xpertius.com', 'No reply');
    $mail->addAddress("$client_email", 'Xpertius');
    $mail->Subject = "Thank You For Appling - '".$job_title."'";
    $mail->msgHTML($htmlbody);
    $uploadfile1 = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['resume']['name']));
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile1);
    $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile1, $head);
```

I have also tried to save it to y database and the file is saving properly but not sending as attached file link is broken in the email

Comment: check for errors. You should also post the html form for this.

Comment: okay I am posting the html no erros are giving emall send successfully but attached file is broken

Comment: i have updates my question please have a look

Comment: I don't know what `tempnam()` does. The syntax to send as an attachment is `addAttachment($tempFile, $fileName)`. I.e.: `$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);`

Comment: I'd suggest you base your code on [the send_file_upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) script that's provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to move your uploaded file:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile1);
```

But you have already moved it in:

```
move_uploaded_file($headtemp, $path.$head);
```

Most probably, the file you try to attach is empty (as is no longer exists), check the size in email, or check before attaching if it still exists.

Therefore, you should define $uploadfile1 as:

```
$uploadfile1 = $path.$head;
```

in place of your second move_uploaded_file.

Comment: The attachment size in email is 0kb

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES["resume"]['tmp_name'],
                     $_FILES["resume"]['name']);
```

also check the folder permission where you want to move the file it should be writable

Comment: The file has already been moved, therefore it will not be accessible at `$_FILES['resume']['tmp_name']`.

Comment: then do it before moving

Comment: No, don't, it's a security risk, as the PHP docs say; you must use `move_uploaded_file` first.

Comment: okay so I have to move the file to the folder after sending email ??

Comment: I used your method and now the email is receiving without attachment

Comment: use first $mail->send() and then move_uploaded_file()